# class org.springframework.data.repository.query.DefaultParameters cannot be cast to class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaParameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a error when setup new project Spring boot 3.2.0.
the terminal show "class org.springframework.data.repository.query.DefaultParameters cannot be cast to class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaParameters".

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the spring-data-commons dependency. I just wanted to note this to help someone with the same problem. I don't know why it works; I hope someone can help me find the answer.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I have the same problem but this fix unfortunately did not work for me.